# Pipeline with services from password protected repository

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to create pipeline with services. Let's say using mysql service

```yaml
services:
  - mysql:latest
```

My project uses docker image from our company repo which is password protected.
When I run it manually I must fist login to repository

```sh
docker login <creadentials> <repository address>
docker pull <some private image>
```

Is there some way to configure gitlab pipeline to use service with credentials?

```yaml
services:
  - <maybe some credentials here???>@<my private host>/modifiedForProductionMysql:latest
```

I know I can use shell runner and call all commands in my shell script. First I wanted to investigate if it is doable with gitlab docker runner and pipeline job with services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using a private container registry](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#using-a-private-container-registry). You can put your credentials into `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable. The format is the same as `~/.docker/config.json` after you login to your registry.