# Cannot connect to postgres in Gitlab CI

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to use GitLab CI PostgreSQL for my integration tests but it doesn´t work.

Here's the code of the stage:

```
integration_test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - custom_tag
  services: 
    - postgres
  variables: 
    POSTGRES_DB: test
    POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  script:
    - docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}
    - docker pull ${DOCKER_IMAGE_CI}
    - export PGPASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    - docker run --rm postgres psql -h ${POSTGRES_HOST} -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "SELECT 'OK' AS status;"
```

It returns an error like this:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
>   Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's better to look at dockerizing test functions. This approach also provides better control over networking by means of docker bridge.
In this way your config could looks like this:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
 - test
before_script:
 - docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}
integration_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose up
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
networks:
  database:
services:
  postgres-db:
    image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_CI}
    networks:
      - database
    container_name: postgres

  test-container:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - database
    container_name: testcon
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB=test \
    POSTGRES_HOST=postgres \
    POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
CMD psql -h ${POSTGRES_HOST} -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "SELECT 'OK' AS status;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline looks like it uses shell executor with gitlab services.

Command `docker run --rm postgres <docker command>` does not automatically connect to postgres network. You could try running your docker image with `--link postgres`, more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). Note that link is legacy feature and may be removed in the future.

Personally I would try running my pipeline job using docker image. If your image is not publicly visible then you can bypass it with `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`

If you used docker runner with [password protected image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450076/pipeline-with-services-from-password-protected-repository) then yaml would look like:

```
integration_test:
  image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_CI}
  stage: test
  tags:
    - custom_tag
  services: 
    - postgres
  variables: 
    POSTGRES_DB: test
    POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  script:
    - PGPASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} psql -h ${POSTGRES_HOST} -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "SELECT 'OK' AS status;"
```

`DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` environment variable would be as follows([gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determining-your-docker_auth_config-data)):

```
{
    "auths": {
        "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}": {
            "auth": "(Base64 content from ${DOCKER_USER}:${DOCKER_PASSWORD})"
        }
    }
}
```

and to generate base64 auth you can use `echo -n "${DOCKER_USER}:${DOCKER_PASSWORD}" | base64`